# Seeing if a notepad contains the same word as the combo box has selected

Tags: c#, file, loops, search, combobox

So what my problem is and i have looked on the internet for this but really cannot find out how to do it.

I want to use my combo box which is populated with items from a notepad. i want the combo box to search through the notepad when an items from the combo box is selected and when it gets a match i want it to return the line number(ID).

This is what i thought would work, but it doesn't full work.

```
int items = File.ReadLines(@"C:\Users\PC\Documents\File\IDs.txt").Count();
string line;
int thisnum;
if (cboItemPick.SelectedIndex != -1)
{
    if (cboItemPick.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <items;)
        {
            items = i;
            line = File.ReadLines(@"C:\Users\PC\Documents\File\IDs.txt").ElementAt(items);

            if (line == cboItemPick.Text)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Boom");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your code will have very bad performances. Please refer to this reviewed example:

```
if( cboItemPick.SelectedItem != null) {
    var filepath = @"C:\Users\PC\Documents\File\IDs.txt";
    var lines = File.ReadLines(filepath);
    var keyword = cboItemPIck.SelectedItem as String;
    for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        var line = lines[i];
        if( string.Compare(line, keyword) == 0) {
            // Good, you have a match!
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Item found at line: {0}", i));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Hey, thx for helping, the only problem i got is that  var line = lines[i]; this isnt recognised, and also, im pretty sure thats not c#. well, might be, i dont know, i know var is a variable, but i have always been learnt to imply it as an int, or a string, if this is c#, where should a var be used? and is it better then putting the datatype there instead?

Comment: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type <--- that is the error that i got btw, just thought i should throw that in there :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(@"C:\Users\PC\Documents\File\IDs.txt");

var result = lines.Select((i, index) => new { Value = i, Index = index }).ToList();

//Check if cboItemPick.SelectedItem is valid and set it to comboboxValue
var lineNumber = result.First(i => i.Value == comboboxValue).Select(i => i.Index);
```